# Need help finding a reCaptcha secret key

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to implement reCaptcha and have gone through the steps on Google's site and have the project created.  After creating a key I can see the Site Key but there is nothing that shows a "secret key".  All the code samples I'm seeing refer to a secret key and I've clicked all over the place, recreated keys, and tried using a different account but I'm only seeing a Site Key ID.  If I click the name and go to the dashboard, I can click the "Key details" link in the upper right corner but it still just shows the Site Key ID.  Where do I find the secret key?